# Commits from branch master appear in other branch - GitHub

Tags: github, git-branch, github-api, branching-and-merging, gitpython

I am analyzing commits from project [apache/mina-sshd](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd) but I am running to a problem:

- All commits in the [branch *0.9.x* from project mina-sshd](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/commits/0.9.x) (except for the first 3 commits) belongs to branch *master* but still be shown in branch *0.9.x*. Can anyone explain this for me, please? I am thinking it might be because those commits are merged, maybe?
- Is there anyway to check what branch a commit belongs to by Python?

Answer (score 0):

Your branch 0.9.x is derived from master. So at the point the branch gets created, it contains all the commits that the other branch has at that point. If you add additional commits to the master after the branch is created, they will not appear anymore unless you merge them.

Comment: So, if I merge branch 0.9.x to master, I will see all commits in branch 0.9.x that are from the beginning up to the point where I merge, right?